# Pressing arrow keys affects the result of a function that takes input values

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, dom

I have a function that takes an `input` value and sums it into a variable which is then shown in a `span` element everytime the "keyup" event is triggered. e.g. I press 1 in my `input` and the `span` shows 1 as well. I want this `span` to only work with numbers. The problem is: if I press any of the arrow keys, this `span` bugs and sums to itself whatever the value the `input` had previously. e.g. I press 3 and the `span` shows it as well, but if I press the left arrow key, the `span` shows 6, I press right arrow key and now it shows 9, etc.

```js
var inputsSum = 0;
let userQuantity = 0;
let totalPrice = document.getElementById("test2");

function calculatePrice() {
    const superChosen = document.getElementById("test");
    superChosen.addEventListener("keyup",evnt=>{
        if(evnt.target.matches("input.q-tints")) {
            userQuantity = parseInt(evnt.target.value);
            if (userQuantity >= 0) inputsSum += userQuantity;
            else if (isNaN(userQuantity)) inputsSum = 0; //Prevents actions from the backspace key
        }
        totalPrice.innerHTML = `${inputsSum},00`;
    })
}

calculatePrice();
```

```html
<div class="super-chosen-color">
   <div class="chosen-color">
       <p class="text-chosen">No color chosen</p>
       <div class="info-chosen">
           <input type="text" name="" id="test" placeholder="0" class="q-tints" autocomplete="off">
           <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="total-value">
    Total
    <span>$</span>
    <span class="p-total" id="test2">
        0,00
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for the `input` event instead of the `keyup` event.

> The **`input`** event fires when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element has been changed.<sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)</sup>

```js
var inputsSum = 0;
var totalPrice = document.querySelector('.p-total');
const superChosen = document.querySelector('input');
function calculatePrice() {
    superChosen.addEventListener("input",evnt=>{
        if(evnt.target.matches("input.q-tints")) {
            userQuantity = parseInt(evnt.target.value);
            if (userQuantity >= 0) inputsSum += userQuantity;
            else if (isNaN(userQuantity)) inputsSum = 0; //Prevents actions from the backspace key
        }
        totalPrice.innerHTML = `${inputsSum},00`;
    })
}

calculatePrice();
```

```html
<div class="super-chosen-color">
   <div class="chosen-color">
       <p class="text-chosen">No color chosen</p>
       <div class="info-chosen">
           <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="0" class="q-tints" autocomplete="off">
           <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="total-value">
    Total
    <span>$</span>
    <span class="p-total">
        0,00
    </span>
</div>
```